# Why is colour of text of my JButton not changing?

Tags: colors, jbutton

frame.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
frame.add(new JButton("blue"));

text stays black when I run it?

Answer (score 0):

unless the name of your button is frame, of course it's not working. Your setting your frame to blue, but your button remains the same color. Your code should look like this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    add(frame, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JButton button = new JButton("blue");
    // button.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    button.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    frame.add(button);
```

Comment: it makes answering your problem easier

Comment: you seem to be new to JButtons, so visit this site --- http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/swing/jbutton.shtml

Comment: it explains the use of JButtons, and explains `ActionListener ` as well as `ActionPerformed`